# Why won't Glide load an image from resource ID to my ImageView?

Tags: android, android-glide

I've got all of the images I need for my app, and I'm trying to speed it up and make it silky smooth, so I have been using Glide to load the images and it works in other areas of my app but not in my viewpager.

In my fragment I'm trying to load my image like so

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.my_drawable).into(myImageView);
```

and nothing happens or appears and I don't get an exception or any sort of error message from Glide.

Comment: inside Fragment you can't pass "this", instead you will pass "getActivity()" to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Debugging and Error Handling](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Debugging-and-Error-Handling) wiki page to enable logging. That should tell you if the load is failing and why.

If you see no error logs, it's possible that your View doesn't have a size, either because its size is 0, or because it hasn't gone through layout (visibility set to `View.GONE` etc). If so, you can test check by adding a call to [`override()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#override(int,%20int)) with any valid width and height (try `400, 400` or something just to test).

If calling `override()` fixes the issue, take a look at your xml and see if you can change your view to either have a fixed size, or to at least eventually end up with a valid size. If all else fails, you can always call `override()` with `Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL` as the width and height.

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is long since closed but I found a good solution for this by using the placeholder or error image instead.
So you might try

```
Glide.with(<<MyActivity>>)
    .load("")
    .placeholder(<<myDrawable>>)
    .into(imageView);
```

Not sure this is what you wanted but if there are others having the same issue, at least this seems to work with a minimum of work. :)

Comment: Struggling from 1 hr to load a picture from resource id in alert dialog. Place holder did the trick.

Comment: .placeholder() is deprecated now. Use `Glide.with(activity).load("").apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(resourceId)).into(imageView)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Tobias Reich's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194273/8072092) generates a bunch of warning logs cause load url is "". If you don't want warning logs,
**Try this:**

```
int drawableIdentifier = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("my_drawable_image_name", "drawable", activity.getPackageName());
Glide.with(activity)
     .load(drawableIdentifier)
     .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Vector or SVG, your version of Glide might not support this and fail to load.